# Line is not covered according to test coverage, despite successfully using verify and asserts

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, sonarqube

My goal is for Sonar to detect that the error thrown in the `MyService` class (pointed through the comment) is actually covered in the test. However, Sonar says it is not. Despite successfully verifying that the `logAndThrowException` method is called, Sonar still says this line is not covered in the test.

MyService class:

```
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MyExceptionHandler myExceptionHandler;

    public ResponseEntity doSomeRequest() {
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

            if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStates.OK) {
                return response;
            }

            myExceptionHandler.logAndThrowException("error"); // Sonar says this line is not covered in tests
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            // Handle it
        }
    }
}
```

MyExceptionHandler class:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler {
    public void logAndThrowException(String msg) throws MyCustomException {
        // do some logs
        throw new MyCustomException();
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate

    @Mock 
    MyExceptionHandler myExceptionHandler;

    @Mock
    ResponseEntity responseEntity;

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService = new MyService();

    @Test
    public void testFailedRequest() {
        when(restTemplate.exchange(any(RequestEntity.class), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
        when(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        Mockito.doThrow(MyCustomException.class).when(myExceptionHandler).logAndThrowException(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());

        assertThrows(MyCustomException.class, () -> myService.doSomeRequest());

        Mockito.verify(myExceptionHandler, Mockito.times(1)).logAndThrowException(ArgumentMatchers.anyString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `Mockito.doThrow(MyCustomException.class, () -> myService.doSomeRequest());` in the test case?

Comment: Sorry - that is incorrect (during the copy pasting I have messed up). I have updated the post, thanks for pointing it out @Smile

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've seen this before.  The issue is that it doesn't "finish" executing that line, because an exception is thrown while executing that line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David! Interesting, so I assume this is something that can't be fixed in the coverage and should be left as is?